On a question about ordinals $\xi$ satisfying $j_0(\xi)=j_1(\xi)$ for an $I_3$-embedding $j$
Let $j\colon V_\lambda\to V_\lambda$ be an $I_3$ embedding with the critical sequence $\kappa_n$. Define $j_0=j$, $j_1 = j[j]=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda} j(j\upharpoonright V_\alpha)$. My question is the following:

For $\xi<\kappa_2$, if $j_0(\xi)=j_1(\xi)$ then $\xi = j_0(\eta)$ for some $\eta$?

Note that the converse is easy to prove: If $\xi=j_0(\eta)$, then $j_1(\xi)=j_0[j_0](j_0(\eta))= j_0(j_0(\eta))=j_0(\xi)$.

Yes. In fact for all ordinals $\xi\notin\mathrm{range}(j_0)$, we have $j_1(\xi)<j_0(\xi)$. For let $\xi$ be an ordinal such that $\xi\notin\mathrm{range}(j_0)$. Let $\gamma$ be least such that $j_0(\gamma)>\xi$, so $\sup(j_0``\gamma)\leq\xi$. Then $j_0(j_0\upharpoonright\gamma) = j_1\upharpoonright j_0(\gamma)$. We have $j_0(\sup j_0``\gamma)=\sup j_1``j_0(\gamma)$. But $\xi<j_0(\gamma)$, so $j_1(\xi)<j_0(\sup j_0``\gamma)$. But $\sup(j_0``\gamma)\leq\xi$, so $j_0(\sup(j_0``\gamma))\leq j_0(\xi)$. Putting these together, we have
$$j_1(\xi)<j_0(\sup j_0``\gamma)\leq j_0(\xi).$$
